# Are log4j.properties file includes supported?

Tags: java, log4j

Does log4j support properties files **includes** - like commons configuration - so I could include one file from another, overriding properties as appropriate?

I have tried doing it, and it doesn't seem to work. Is there an alternate way to achieve the same reuse?

Comment: I don't know if I understand the question/ what you are trying to do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it doesn't. All configuration must go into a single `log4j.properties` or `log4j.xml` file.

Answer (score 2):

You can use XML entity expansion as an include mechanism in log4j.xml.

Comment: Start your XML with:

<!DOCTYPE project [
  <!ENTITY ant_common_properties SYSTEM "ant_common_properties.xml">
  <!ENTITY ant_common_targets SYSTEM "ant_common_targets.xml">
]>

Then expand the entity using the following syntax:

 &ant_common_properties;

Comment: Does anybody have a reference to an example github project that does this? I think that'd be really useful.